# How do I split a TD string into new rows at the nth occurrence only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code splits the text of each row in to newly created rows at a certain delimiter.
By changing the second parameter of the splice method a starting point can be given. Everything after the starting delimiter occurence will be splitted and put on a new row

How do I split only the nth occurence of a delimeter? (i.e. the second)

The desired result should be something like this: Start splitting at the second '/' delimiter:

this:
**PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY**

becomes:
**PMC37516JG/DMM

1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY**

```js
$('#tbl tr').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var arr = $this.text().split('/');
  var firstTwo = arr.splice(0,2);
  var firstEl = firstTwo.join('/').trim();
  arr.unshift(firstEl);
  var len = arr.length;
  var i;
  var $previous = $this;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var $tr = $this.clone();
    $tr.find("td").text(arr[i]); 
    $previous.after( $tr );
    $previous = $tr;
  }
  $this.remove();
});
```

```css
th {
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
td {
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tbl-header">
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>UWS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your script to below one and please verify if this works for you.

```
$('#tbl tr').each(function(){
      var tr = $(this).find('td').text().split('/');
    if (tr.length > 2){
    //you can change below code to split it by first '/'
        var p =tr.splice(0,2);
    $(this).replaceWith('<tr><td>' +p.join('/') +'</td></tr> <tr><td>'+tr.join('/') +'</td></tr>') 
    }

    });
```

Comment: Manoj Yadav, your code works, except when trying to cut at the first occurrence only. It seems to work in all other cases. When trying to split at the first occurence of a delimter only all occurrences will be splitted into new rows.

Comment: can you share an example?

Comment: I just updated code with some comments and also swaped tr with p. Please check if this works for you